# Equivalence definition of creation of limits?

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

The following is at Emily Riehl’s Category theory in context, page 90.

Firstly the Definition of creation of limits:

> **Definition 3.3.1.** : For any class of diagrams $K : J → C$ valued in $C$, a functor $F : C 
> → D$  creates those limits if whenever $FK : J → D$ has a limit in 
>   $D$, there is some limit cone over $FK$ that can be lifted to a limit 
>   cone over $K$, and moreover $F$ reﬂects the limits in the class of 
>   diagrams.

But later the author writes the following at the same page, which I think is a weaker hypothesis than that in **Definition 3.3.1**, because it seems not to require the limit cone existing in $C$ to be a lift of a limit cone in $D$.

> *Remark 3.3.2*. To ground intuition for these terms, the following metaphor may prove helpful: a functor $F : C → D $ maps from
>   “upstairs” (the category $C$) to “downstairs” (the category $D$). An
>   upstairs diagram (a functor $K : J → C$) sits above a downstairs
>   diagram (by composing with $F$).
>
> **$F$ creates limits if the mere presence of a downstairs limit cone
>    implies the existence of an upstairs limit cone, and if any cone
>    sitting above a limit cone is a limit cone.**

May I miss something? Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a weaker hypothesis. The formal definition supposed that $F$ lifts and reflects limits, while the intuitive one suppose only that $F$ reflects limits and the existence of limits. As long as $\mathcal C$ has limits, the formal definition implies that $F$ preserves them, but the intuitive one does not, so is missing a piece of the concept.